# How to get a custom name of Session cookie configured on context.xml

Tags: java, spring, catalina

I have a REST Service that receives an HttpServletRequest and I need to load the session cookies for this object. If there is no change, I can load by the name which is JSESSIONID, but this name can be changed in the context.xml as it is in the example.

```
<Context sessionCookieName="CUSTOMSESSIONID">

    <!-- Default set of monitored resources. If one of these changes, the    -->
    <!-- web application will be reloaded.                                   -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
    <!--
    <Manager pathname="" />
    -->
</Context>
```

```
public List<Cookie> collectCookies(HttpServletRequest request) {
        if (request.getCookies() != null) {
            final List<Cookie> cookiesList = Arrays.asList(request.getCookies());
            
                return cookiesList.stream()
                        .filter(
                                cookie ->
                                        "JSESSIONID".equals(cookie.getName())
                                                || "ApplicationGatewayAffinity".equals(cookie.getName()))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        }
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

What service can / should I use in order to know what name is being used for the session cookie?

Thanks for your help.